# Sending more than one model to view MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have two model classes, each is a table in a database. One model is called 'Clothes' and the other 'Shoes'.

I want to display the contents of each table in the same razor view, but MVC is only letting me send one model to the view.

```
@model IEnumerable<Test.Models.Clothes>
```

Is there a way to send more than one model to a razor view?

If not, what is the normal way to display contents of another model in a view that has already got another model passed to it. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Either make a view model class which has both the class as its object. It would be then type safe.

```
public class ViewModelForDisplay
{
       public Clothes Clothes {get; set;}
       public Shoes Shoes {get; set;}
}

//on Controller
Clothes objClothes = GetClothes();
Shoes objShoes = GetShoes();

ViewModelForDisplay objViewModel = new ViewModelForDisplay() {Clothes = objClothes, Shoes= objShoes }
```

The other easy way to do it by using ViewBag.It uses the dynamic feature that was added in to C# 4. It allows an object to dynamically have properties added to it. Its also Type Safe

```
ViewBag.Shoes= objShoes ;
ViewBag.Clothes= objClothes ;
```

You could also use ViewData to pass objects to html. BUt this would not be type safe. It requires casting

```
ViewData["Clothes "] = objClothes ;
ViewData["Shoes "] = objShoes ;
```

Comment: View Model is the preferred approach.

Comment: Furthermore it's not a good idea to pass your model (the database object) to the view. Create a ViewModel only with the required fields

Comment: Thanks for replay and giving code sample, any chance of expanding on the controller? It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Make your own class aka View Model and have it composed of both models.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this article very interesting :

https://workspaces.codeproject.com/user-10826818/using-multiple-models-in-a-view-in-asp-net-mvc-4

It presents different ways to send multiple models to a view :

- ViewData
- ViewBag
- PartialView
- TempData
- ViewModel
- Tuple