# Info from database in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to insert a condition in my view. The condition is based on information from the database. What is the best way to do this? I considered inserting that value into `ViewBag` in controller or creating an additional property in the view model, but they are dirty ways and I would prefer to avoid them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed definition of what 'condition' you want

Comment: @Daniel Dawes: I think the kind of condition does not  matter. I need some info from db and construct the condition based on them.

Comment: @pt12lol The reason I ask is condition could mean anything, from 'if this... then that...' to 'show this template if status is that, or throw this error if message is this...' etc.

Comment: @Daniel Dawes: I see. I want to enable or disable for edit some list items if condition is true or false.

Comment: Bind to a ViewModel and then you can use razor syntax to do something like @if (condition){ <span>true</span> }else{<span>false</span>}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a ViewModel(it represents the data that you want to display on the page), if you think the property does not fit in your model.

I am assuming you would be using the property to hide and show some elements.

See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498399/sending-more-than-one-model-to-view-mvc-4/11498422#11498422) on various ways to send extra information to view

Comment: @pt12lol It does sound like you should be using a ViewModel as shown above, and binding any conditions you might have to that model.
See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548376/asp-net-mvc-how-exactly-to-use-view-models

Comment: I see. But as I mentioned in my question, I would prefer to avoid that way. Do you think it is the best way to do this? I am sorry I didn't precise what I understand under `model` word.